Error when updating in WordPress: Unexpected error while rendering a file in the AssetBuilder: Unrecognized asset name: angular-modules.json
I'm trying to update civiCRM on WordPress from version 5.66.00 to 5.70.2.
I delete the plugins/civiCRM folder, and then unzip civicrm-5.70.2-wordpress.zip
I then browser to [domain]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 and click the Update button, and after a few moments, I'm redirected to the home page of my site.
When I look in the ConfigAndLog error log, I see this:
[error] Unexpected error while rendering a file in the AssetBuilder: Unrecognized asset name: angular-modules.json
I have Angular Profiles extension installed. I try to disable it, but it appears that CiviVolunteer is dependent on it, and I cannot disable it. Nor can I disable CiviVolunteer.
Anyone have any ideas what I should do next / how I can resolve this issue so I can complete my upgrade?
